# How can I create variables by iterating through a combination of integers and strings?

Tags: python, variables, loops

So I want to create variables by looping through some sort of name assigning statement or function. I want to end up having variables titled "`t1`, `t2`, `t3`" etc. How can I accomplish what

```
i = 1
while 1:
    ("t" + str(i)) = [0,0,0,0]
    i = i + 1
```

looks like it would do. (Keep the `str("t")` at the front than make the second character the changing `int(i)`. This is to create variables to later put in an array without having to type them out in the the code.) I'm trying to make a list of 10,000 lists with 4 elements each. Is this more clear?

Comment: If you're just going to put them in an array later, why not just put them in an array now?

Comment: They need to originally be defined first.

Comment: Why do they need be defined first?

Comment: @Zizma: why? I'm having trouble thinking of any scenario in which you couldn't just make an array from the beginning. If you could edit your question to explain that, it would help a lot.

Comment: From what you wrote (infinite loop notwithstanding), it looks like you really want a list `t = [foo]*n`, where `n` is the number of elements of `foo` that you want.

Comment: @kindall: Will it not throw and error when trying to access a not previously defined variable?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: When I'm working with 10,000 variables?

Comment: Why would you try to access the elements of the array using variable names?

Comment: 99.999% of the time, when someone thinks, "I want to dynamically name variables," they're wrong.

Comment: @Wooble: How else would I do it?

Comment: @Zizma (4 comments up): so? Why couldn't you just make an array (actually a list, in Python) with 10000 elements?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to do; almost certainly you're looking for a list named `t`, with elements accessed as `t[0]`, `t[1]`, etc.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: Manually typing them into the code?

Comment: @Wooble: No, I don't want separate elements. I want separate variables.

Comment: @Zizma: you wouldn't have to manually type them into the code, though. I still don't see any reason for you not to create a list. In order to be convinced otherwise, I would like to see a _complete_ sample program that illustrates what you are doing with these variables (you don't have to include all 10000 of them, of course; just 5 or so to show the pattern).

Comment: What exactly do you imagine having the name `t65342` referencing some object is going to do for you if you're going to need some ugly `eval` magic to access it?

Comment: Ill just edit my original post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is technically possible to do what you want, it's a really bad practice. This is exactly the use case that lists (or arrays) were made for, and you should be using one here.

Based on your code sample, something like

```
t = [[0] * 4 for i in xrange(10000)]
```

(as David Alber mentioned in a comment) should work for you; it will create a list of 10000 lists of 4 elements each.

P.S. In Python 3, the `xrange` function has been renamed to `range`.

Comment: Thank you! Both yours and David Albers answer will work. Is there a way to check both? :)

Comment: You mean accept? No, you can only accept one answer. But you can upvote both.

Comment: @Zizma This answer is incorrect. It creates a list of 10000 references to a single list of 4 elements. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: @Ben to be fair, in the original version of the question the sample code did create a list of 10000 copies of the same object. In any case, that's a very minor issue and you could have just mentioned it in a comment, rather than creating an entirely separate "attack answer".

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Sorry, I didn't mean it as an "attack". Indeed I started writing my answer as a comment here, but as Zizma seems to be a Python beginner I wanted to go into more detail (and use examples) than was possible in a comment. It's true Zizma's original code also have this flaw (ignoring others), but given Zizma's stated intention (to create a whole bunch of variables, which must be then modified to be any use) this is clearly not what Zizma wanted.

Comment: @Ben, okay, understood :-) You came off kind of harsh - though maybe it's just me, it has been a long day.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky No, you're right, my language could have been more respectful. I've reworded it slightly; hopefully it's better now! :) I was trying to be emphatic, to get attention if Zizma doesn't yet know enough about Python internals to immediately understand the difference between your suggestion and mine.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky So I just realized that the original answer indeed didn't work but now I am having troubles with the new answers with the for loop. What should xrange be defined as?

Comment: @Zizma I'm not sure what you mean, `xrange` is a builtin function (unless you're using Python 3 in which case use `range` instead)

Comment: Yes I am using Python 3. It now works perfectly. Thanks for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Don't try.

Instead, use a single dictionary to keep all the values - your titles can be the keys:

```
my_dict = {}
for i in range(1, 4):
    my_dict['t%s' % i] = foo
```

Comment: Will this create separate variables?

Comment: Although this is technically better than creating individual variables, I still couldn't recommend using a dict over a list here.

Answer (score 3):

`t = [[0] * 4] * 10000` works, but probably doesn't do what you expect. Rather than creating a list of 10000 lists, it will create a list of 10000 *references* to a **single** list. Have a look at what happens when you try to start changing elements of the inner lists:

```
>>> t = [[0] * 4] * 3
>>> t
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> t[0][0] = 1
>>> t
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Instead, the following is probably what you were expecting:

```
>>> t = [[0] * 4 for _ in xrange(3)]
>>> t
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> t[0][0] = 1
>>> t
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The reason is that multiplying a list just creates a longer list with multiple references to the elements inside the original list. This is almost never a good idea unless you **know** the list contains entirely immutable objects (such as numbers and strings); that's why it's still okay to use list multiplication in `[0] * 4` in my version of the answer, even though the outer list multiplication in `[[0] * 4] * 10000` is dangerous.